# JavaScript object prototype Poisoning

Tags: javascript

I was trying to learn how object.prototype function in javascript then I came across this snippet of code .which I don't understand?

```
// Poisoning Object.prototype
Object.prototype.bar = 1;
var foo = {goo: undefined};

foo.bar; // 1
'bar' in foo; // true

foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'); // false
foo.hasOwnProperty('goo'); // true
```

foo has the property bar which is defined in the line number 3 and having the value of undefined .Please guide then why `foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')` returns `false` in this case

Comment: best to read the MDN [documentation on hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: It does not *have* it, it *inherits* it. That's the whole point of prototypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All objects in JavaScript are descended from `Object`. all objects inherit methods and properties from `Object.prototype`.

In your example when you try to get the `foo.bar`, it doesn't find `bar` in the `foo`, so it is going to the prototype of the `foo` and tries to find it there.

`hasOwnProperty` - only checks a property which is exactly in the your `foo`.

Here is what your `foo` looks like

[image]

**For deep understanding you can read this chapter.**

[You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md)

Answer (score 0):

The `foo` object has a `bar` property because it inherits it from `Object` as `bar` was added to the Object prototype.  `foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')` returns false because `foo` does not define `bar`, `Object` does.

Comment: but there ; we have written `foo.bar` .doesn't it create a property named bar in foo. To create property it have to be write like this ` foo['bar']`

Comment: @ankyAS No, the property already existed, but Foo does not own the property.  Foo inherits from Object so it gets all properties that Object declares, including bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple goo is the direct property of foo, but to get bar it is required to traverse the prototype chain. hasOwnProperty only check for its direct property.